# Import data into MySQL table having a unique constraint

Tags: mysql, excel, import

I’m having trouble importing data into MYSQL database.

Scenario: Import data into (person) table from Excel but what if the email already existed in the  (person) table?

I can’t execute the import features of PHPMYADMIN because once the record or email are already existed in the (person) table it will return an error. (prn_email is unique).

Is there any way to import the data into MYSQL then it will disregard all existed emails and continue importing the new data?

Comment: is it ok for you with duplicate prn_email data?

Comment: nope... i want to import those emails that is not in the system yet. But some of the data(email) in my excel file already existed. I dont want to removed them one by one coz its thousands of records.

Comment: @MichaelPhilip Have you tried using "Remove Duplicates" function in Excel for removing the records before importing them into MySQL?

Comment: I used Excel formula to concatenate SQL statement for each record. SQL statement should include “ON DUPLICATE UPDATE”.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure this is the easiest way to do this, but this might work for you:
1) create a duplicate table with all the column names exactly the same and only the table name different (this can be deleted after you're finished).
2) import your data into the blank table.
3) export your data as a mysqldump.
4) edit the resulting file in a text editor by adding ' ignore ' after each instance of 'insert'. Also, replace each instance of the duplicate table's name with the real table name.  Save the file.
5) import the file as a mysqldump.